# Logic Grid Interpretation of Clues ("Above the Summits")

Tags: logic-grid

I have been stuck on [this logic grid](https://www.brainzilla.com/logic/logic-grid/above-the-summits/) for a few hours. I don't know how to interpret Clue 4, 5, or 7.

- What does "next to" refer to in Clue 4?
- Can I then deduct that Everest is not in America from Clue 5?
- How does Clue 7 help if I don't know where Vinson is, or whether Kilimanjaro was conquered in 1966?

Can someone help me solve this, or let me know how to interpret those clues? Thanks.

> 1. Purtscheller's peak and the Aconcagua were conquered in the same century.  2. Mount Vinson is in Antarctica or was conquered in 1889. Hillary didn't go to either places.
>   3. The four mountains are: the African one, the mount reached by Zurbriggen, the mount reached in 1966, and the Everest.  4. Clinch reached the goal immediately next to the explorer who went to Asia.
>   5. Purtscheller didn't climb the Everest, and didn't lead an expedition to America.
>   6. Among Zurbriggen and Hillary, one went to Asia, the other climbed a mountain in 1897.  7. If the Vinson is in America, then the Kilimanjaro was conquered in 1966.

Edit: included the title "Above the Summits" in case other people are stuck on it.

Comment: How come clue 2 doesn't confuse you? :)

Comment: How the hell do you proceed from here: https://i.imgur.com/WFNItDi.png

Comment: @Ardweaden yeah, I'm wondering if this puzzle is poorly written, or if I'm just not seeing the solution. Could you please tell me how you deducted marking off Antarctica and Asia for 1889 (bottom left of the grid)?

Comment: @eric Antarctica: Clue 2. If mount Vinson is in Antarctica, it wasn't conquered in 1889. If it isn't in Antarctica, it was conquered in 1889. Asia: Clue 4. We know that Clinch is not 1897, so if Asia was in 1889 (which wasn't Clinch), Clinch wouldn't be right next to that explorer.

Comment: @Ardweaden Thank you for explaining. My problem is I'm not sure how to interpret "next to" in Clue 4. You interpreted it as Clinch and Asia's explorer having years next to each other (which very well might be correct); to me the clue is too vague to tell. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, I just went with JMP's interpretation. It makes sense, because "immediately" does refer to time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have taken JMP and Ardweaden's suggestion that Clue 4's "next to" means Clinch's year is right next to Asia explorer's year on the grid.

Then I have decided alone to take Clue 7's reverse to be true: if Vinson is not in America, then Kilimanjaro is not 1966.

After these 2 decisions, I was able to solve this poorly-written puzzle. Based on other puzzles, it seems the site has typos and grammar mistakes in general.

Comment: But what *is* the solution? As it stands, this post doesn't really provide an answer.

Comment: My question wasn't about the solution to the whole puzzle, but about what clue 4 and 7 (and 5) mean. About the actual solution, this puzzle happens to be about real-world geography and history, so people can literally google "who discovered mount ..." or "what year was mount ... discovered", etc.

Answer (score 1):

4.

> I think 'next' in this case means an adjacent year.

5.

> No. This apple is not brown. This apple is not a vegetable. There are therefore no brown vegetables (potato).

7.

> You can only conclude one if the other is true. If either is false, you know nothing.

Comment: Thanks. For Clue 7, I think it is an if p then n, which means if not n, then not p. (So if Kilimanjaro was not conquered in 1966, then Vinson is not in America.) But I just don't know how this clue would help unless I was almost done solving already.